# Is it safe to use instance variables to store transient properties of ActiveRecord objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

**I need to store an encoding-state value on a video while it's been encoded**

I have a video object. While the video is being encoded it needs to lock edits on its comments.

The video therefore needs to store its current encoding state (is it happening yes/no?) and allow child comments to query that property.

**Please note**

*I know that there are better ways to solve this particular problem. I actually need to solve a slightly different problem however I felt the nuances of it would confuse the question so I've chosen this one instead. My question is specifically around the nuances of isntance variables and not how to better-solve this encoding problem (which obviously needs a queue).*

```
class Video

  has_many :comments

  after_initialize do
    @encoding_in_process = false
  end

  def encode
    @encoding_in_process = true
    ...
    @encoding_in_process = false
  end

  def encoding_in_process? 
    @encoding_in_process
  end
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :video

  before_update
    raise "locked" if video.encoding_in_process?
  end

  ...
end
```

As you can see, each video instance is storing an instance variable `@encoding_in_process` which is used to determine whether a comment can be updated.

**The problem**

There is a danger there will be multiple in-memory instances of *the same video* each with different values for `@encoding_in_process`.

e.g.

```
bieber_video = Video.find_all_by_artist('Bieber').last
bieber_video.encode 
# assume this takes a while...
bieber_video.encoding_in_process?
# => true

bieber_copy = Video.find_by_id bieber_video.id
bieber_copy.encoding_in_process?
# => false


# Each ActiveRecord objects refer to the same Bieber video
bieber_copy.id == bieber_video.id
# => true

# ...however they refer to different objects in memory:
puts bieber_video
#<Video:0x00000105a9e948>
puts bieber_copy
#<Video:0x00000105a11111>

# and hence each instance has a different version of commenting_locked?
# bieber_video.encoding_in_process? != bieber_copy.encoding_in_process?
```

**The question**

Given that the same database row might generate two different in-memory instances, what is a safe way to store transient non-database-backed information about those instances?

**EDIT**

The *actual* problem I'm trying to solve is setting a flag on an object when `destroy` is initiated such that its child objects can determine whether or not they're eligible to be destroyed themselves.

It's therefore a very instantaneous problem and not suitable for backing into the database. I used this video example because I thought it was a bit clearer however I may have simply muddied the waters.

**THE SOLUTION (courtesy of one of the answers below**

@Alex D's suggestion did solve the problem but to add further clarity to this for anyone wanting to repeat, the actual code was this:

```
class Video
  # set a class variable containing an array of all videos
  # which are currently being encoded
  @@ids_of_videos_being_encoded = []
  ...

  def encode
    store_encoding_state true
    begin
      encode()
    ensure
      # make sure we switch this off after 
      # encoding finishes or fails
      store_encoding_state false
    end
  end

  private  
    def store_encoding_state encoding_in_progress
      if encoding_in_progress
        @@ids_of_videos_being_encoded.push(id)
      else
        @@ids_of_videos_being_encoded.delete(id)
      end
    end

    def encoding_initiated?
      @@ids_of_videos_being_encoded.include? id
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on whether you may use multiple server processes or not. If you may want to run multiple server processes (which is a good assumption), the problem is not just multiple in-memory ActiveRecord objects representing the same DB row, the problem is multiple objects *in different memory spaces*.

If you have multiple processes which are somehow collaboratively working with the same data, you *must* keep that data in a shared store (i.e. a database), and you must flush changes to the store, and refresh your in-memory data as needed. In this case, you *cannot* rely on transient in-memory data being kept in synchronization (because there is no way it possibly could be).

If constantly writing/reading your transient data to the DB sounds expensive, that's because it is. In general, whenever you have multiple processes (on the same or different servers) working together, you want to design things so each process can grab a chunk of data and work on it for a while without having to communicate with the others. Fine-grained data sharing in a distributed system = bad performance.

If you are sure that you will only ever use a single server process, and you want to simulate the effect of instance variables which are shared between multiple ActiveRecord objects representing the same DB row, keep the data in a hash, keyed by the record ID, and use getters/setters which read/write the hash. If you are doing a lot of this, you can do some metaprogramming "magic" to have the getters/setters automatically generated (a la "attr_accessor"). If you need help writing that metaprogramming code, post a question and I'll answer it.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that's really helpful. Am I definitely right in thinking that one can't expect the instance variables to have the same values then (even given single-server)?

Comment: And secondly, if you were to use a cached hash where would you store it - as a class variable?

Comment: In the "attr_accessor" method (I would call it "shared_attr"), I would store the hash in a local variable, and then "close over" it with a closure (passed to define_method).

Comment: Where were you thinking of putting the local variable? You can't store it in a local variable because it just gets you back to square one - it ends up being vulnerable to a different instance being called. I'm actually thinking of storing it as a class variable on the Video class itself. That way all instances will access exactly the same data

Comment: You can store it in a local variable, because the variable is "closed over" by closures (i.e. blocks), and the closures become methods (by passing them to define_method). So you end up with a variable which is shared by *those method bodies only*. Try this: class C; end; i = 0; C.send(:define_method,:inc) { i += 1 }; c = C.new; c.inc; c.inc; Then try creating another instance of C and call inc on it. See what happens.

Comment: If you want to master Ruby, it would be a good idea to do some reading about closures until you really understand them well. It will open up a world of possibilities. BTW, I just pushed some code you can refer to at https://github.com/alexdowad/showcase/blob/master/rubber.rb. It's not tested yet, but it gives you the idea.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Understanding closures was hugely valuable to me in Javascript however I haven't yet taken the time to understand them in the same way in Ruby. I'm going to take a look at your code and see if I can make it work. Meanwhile a hash stored on the class itself has currently solved the problem

Comment: If you understand them in Javascript, you understand them in Ruby. It's the same old thing. In Javascript you can close over local variables too!

Comment: @Peter Nixey, I disaproved your edit. Rather update your question with the correct solution instead.

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman - I've moved it back into the question. Why do you feel it isn't better to keep it attached to the answer? It feels clearer there

Comment: It prevents million of people having better solution to start updating someone else's post and eventually confusing the hell out of the readers. I'm allowing this to be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

> The video therefore needs to store its current encoding state (is it happening yes/no?) and allow child comments to query that property.

IMO, that's not a good way to do this because of all the synchronization issues that will ensue.

A much better strategy is to start off all videos in an `unencoded` state, which you store with the video record's metadata. When a video data stream is created, enqueue an encoding task for some worker to carry out. The worker thread will encode the videos, and when it's done, it should update the video's state to `encoded`.

Now there's no transient state issues; the next time someone tries to comment when the encoding is finished, it'll be done.

> Given that the same database row might generate two different in-memory instances, what is a safe way to store transient non-database-backed information about those instances?

If they don't need to be synchronized, then there isn't an issue. If they *do* need to be synchronized, you run the risk of a race condition. You can also call `.reload` to refresh an object's state from the database.

And if the data needs to be synchronized like that, then you probably *do* need to store it. In the video encoding example, you should either store each video's encoded/unencoded state or provide an implicit, authoritative way of knowing whether the video is encoded or not.

---

**Update from the original question:**

> The actual problem I'm trying to solve is setting a flag on an object when destroy is initiated such that its child objects can determine whether or not they're eligible to be destroyed themselves.

Just use the **[`after_destroy` callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)** to invoke an appropriate method on each child object, and let them determine whether they should be destroyed or not. That will look something like this:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_destroy :purge_pending_comments!

  def purge_pending_comments!
    comments.map &:destroy_if_pending
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but as I mentioned at the start this was a contrived example to show the issues around storing instance variables on ActiveRecord objects (which is my actual question)

Comment: My point is that if you need to synchronize state that way, you shouldn't be using instance variables. It's not unsafe per se (nothing about instance variables prohibits a synchronization strategy), but neither is it a good approach, because there's usually a much easier alternative.

Comment: I do understand that. The issue is that I actually need to use the instance variable for a different task (`before_destroy`) to set a flag on an object showing that `destroy` has been instantiated while its children do some checks to see whether they too can be destroyed. I felt that confused the question so I simplified it to this encoding issue. I do understand your point and solution to this problem - it's good - however it doesn't address the instance variable issue I have.

Comment: @PeterNixey Obviously if you're not backing the AR record instance variable in something globally-accessible, you'll have issues. You could keep something in a global variable, keyed by ID, but I don't understand why you're not backing it in the DB if it's directly related to an object in the DB. If your example doesn't accurately reflect the problem, maybe a different example.

Comment: Thanks gents - you're both right and I've clearly confused the question with this example. I've added clarity to the question to try and make it a bit more specific

Comment: I updated my answer based on your additional information. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi John, I really appreciate all your input on this and I feel bad that I'm not able to mark it as right. The problem is that my question is specifically about the characteristics of instance variables rather than how to solve any particular problem. That's my fault in loose phrasing - I apologise

Comment: @PeterNixey: If that's the case, then I think my answer is the same as before: "It's not unsafe per se (nothing about instance variables prohibits a synchronization strategy), but neither is it a good approach, because there's usually a much easier alternative." (Also, don't feel bad about not awarding imaginary Internet points. :) )

Comment: @JohnFeminella - lol. Ty. After having experimented for the past couple of hours I've realised that the one way I can create a golden data source is by using a class variable. I can store a hash of state for each object ID in the class and then update and access that accordingly. Does that sound sensible?

Comment: That would only work if your environment is constrained to a single memory space. It would break immediately if you had more than one process, for example. If this is a toy/hobby app that you just want to get working, then go for it, but if this is a production app, I still think my suggestion is better.